# Need to merge two .TXT files horizontally without whitespaces and results not being visible in Terminal

Tags: terminal

I have very large TXT files that I need to merge horizontally without leaving whitespaces. Please see the example below.

FILE1.txt

1

2

3

FILE2.txt

A

B

C

NEEDED OUTPUT FILE3.txt

1A

2B

3C

I currently use these 2 commands below to get the desired result, but would like to use just 1 command line because of the huge file size. I also need the results to be saved to an output file without being visible in Terminal.

paste -d ' ' FILE1.txt FILE2.txt | tee -a FILE3.txt

cat FILE3.txt | tr -d "[:blank:]"

Answer (score 0):

Using the paste tool with \0 as a delimitator will do this.

```
paste -d'\0' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```